# How to properly use the sheets.spreadsheets.values.GET in the Google Sheets API?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

So I'm a first year programming student with near 0 experience so please forgive me if I'm going at this the wrong way.
I'm building a website that will take an array of strings and display them as well as run some code relating to those strings. For this assignment, I have to use an API, so I wanted to use the google sheets API in order to achieve my idea. I understand that I need to use the command

```
sheets.spreadsheets.values.GET
```

to get my spreadsheet data as a JS array, which is perfect for what I want to do. Inside the Google dev console, I am able to test the command and receive my array, so I know that I have the API se t up correctly.
However when I go to my website, which has Jquery linked fyi, and I put in the get command into the console I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

This is weird to me since I'm just copy-pasting from the Dev console into the early version of my website this command:

```
GET https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/MY_Spread_Sheet_ID/values/Sheet1!A1%3AA200?valueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&key={ApiKeyCode}
```

I was under the impression that the console should have reported back the contents of my spreadsheet as an array, but instead I get the error.

At first I thought that I must have needed to link the google sheets API to my code like you would with JQuery but I can't find documentation on how to do that, so that might be my problem.

Sorry about my poor English skills.

Comment: Could you include your code in your post? FYI, the function `spreadsheets.values.get()` does not return directly a value, but instead it calls a callback function with the returned values.

Comment: Jess, your comment saved my life. I've been treating get as a method. I've got it working now! Thanks so much.

Comment: That's great, I will post this as an answer. Kindly accept my answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you include your code in your post? FYI, the function spreadsheets.values.get() does not return directly a value, but instead it calls a callback function with the returned values.